# Conditional Formating if cell contains certain characters

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need to come to a custom formula in Google sheets that highlights a cell in the column if the cell contains certain characters in Cyrillic letter.

Some of the Cyrillic characters that look like the Latin characters but are completely different letters:

```
ЕеТтУуОоХхАаСсКкЗзВвНнМм
```

So I am trying to highlight the cell only if there is one of those characters
For example if there is an "А" (Cyrillic) instead of "A" (Latin)

Product Special (* by ones that should be highlighted)

```
Product1    NAXH
Product2    RAHU
Product3    RАHU*
Product4    XBCD
Product5    ХВСD*
Product6    ААЕЕ*
Product7    AAEE
Product8    OООЕ*
```

[image: Some characters are Latin and other Cyrillic but you can't say which is what at a glance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a regex match with all your characters.

```
=REGEXMATCH($B2, "[ЕеТтУуОоХхАаСсКкЗзВвНнМм]")
```

Just place all characters you want to match in between the square brackets.

Here is my result

[image: google sheets result]

---

To learn more about regex, I'd suggest checking out [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/).